# How to change model argument in inlineformset_factory?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

It all works according to that logic. There is a **Project** model that contains general information about the project. Many users can work on this project (model **Employee**) and perform their part of the project work (model **Work**).
I created a view for edditing forms using inlineformset_factory.

**forms.py**

```
ProjectEditFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, Work,
                                       form=WorkCreateForm,
                                       extra=0)
```

**models.py**

```
class Work(models.Model):
    """On which projects an employee has worked."""

    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee_projects')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_work')
    start_year = models.CharField('work start year', max_length=4, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    start_month = models.CharField('work start month', max_length=10, default=datetime.datetime.now().month)
    end_year = models.CharField('work end year', max_length=4, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    end_month = models.CharField('work end month', max_length=10, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    responsibility = models.TextField("employee work responsibility", blank=True)
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField(
        Technology, verbose_name="technologies used on the project")

class Project(models.Model):
    """Project information."""

    name = models.CharField("project name", max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField("project description")
```

**views.py**

```
class WorkEditView(AuthorizedMixin, UpdateView):
    """
    Edit new project instances
    """
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = 'work_edit.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project_form'] = ProjectEditFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        project_form = WorkFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        if form.is_valid() and project_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, project_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, project_form)


    def form_valid(self, form, project_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        project_form.instance = self.object
        project_form.save()
        return redirect('{}#experience'.format(reverse('profile', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['employee']})))
```

*How it works for me now.*

When editing, displayed all the Work forms related to the project (form for each user involved in the project)

*What do I want to get as a result*

Only the editing form belonging to the current user, whose profile is being edited, is displayed.

**urls.py**

```
 path('work/<int:employee>/<int:pk>/edit/', WorkEditView.as_view(), name='work_info_edit'),
```

where `<int:employee>` - current employee; `<int:pk>` - Project id

I think I need to change

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(WorkEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['project_form'] = ProjectEditFormSet(instance=self.object)  <--Smth here need change ??????
```

but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Override the `queryset` when instantiating your `ProjectEditFormSet`, as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-custom-queryset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like with any `ModelFormSet`, you can specify a `queryset` argument when instantiating your `ProjectEditFormSet`:

```
employee_id = self.kwargs['employee']
employee = Employee.objects.get_or_404(id=employee_id)
project_form = ProjecEditFormSet(request.POST, instance=self.object, 
    queryset=Work.objects.filter(employee=employee))
```